# Comparing each part of array of arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays

Quite a few posts on this but can't find one that matches my issue.  In my 'arrays of arrays' I'd like to test if all 'sets' contained in 'SEMI' are present in 'FULL'.  I'm able to do this - see https://jsfiddle.net/v1whs0us/.   But I'd like there to be an alert of the specific set in 'SEMI' that doesn't match.

For example, below code correctly returns 'false', but I'd also like the set ['Netherlands','PP7a'] to be in an alert as the problem that causes the mismatch.  Note that any or all of the Countries and codes in 'SEMI' could be problem matches.  Any ideas much appreciated.

```
console.clear()

var FULL = [['Netherlands','PP3a'],['Luxembourg','PP3a'],['Belgium','PP3a']];
var SEMI   = [['Luxembourg','PP3a'],['Netherlands','PP7a']];


const lookup = (ar, sets) => {
  const _hashed = ar.map(i => i.join(''))
  return sets.every((set) => {
    const _set = set.join('')
    return _hashed.indexOf(_set) > -1
  })
}

console.log(lookup(FULL, SEMI)) // true
```

Comment: something like this https://jsfiddle.net/v1whs0us/1/?

Comment: Wow that's so close.  But if I put a mistake in each set, eg if I also put the Luxembourg code as 'PP6a', I'd like the alert to identify both mistakes. Possible?

Comment: try now https://jsfiddle.net/v1whs0us/2/

Comment: Spot on.  Your help much appreciated - learned a lot from this.

Comment: No problem happy to help